# Insert if doesn't exist otherwise update the record

Tags: mysql

Can someone please help me write a query? I will be inserting data into MySQL database on daily basis using a python script source file which will contain records to date. However, I only want to insert those records which are new and have not already been inserted. But if non-primary key columns have been updated for those records then I want to update the existing record.

Requirements:
1. Insert new record.
2. If record exists(for PK) then do not add record.
3. If record exists(for PK) but non primary keys are changed then update existing record(for PK).

```
CREATE TABLE `S_account` (
  `Sub` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccTeam` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terr` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccOwner` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Level1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GAccount` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customer` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndCus` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AccID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: as far as I can see, this has only one PK?

Comment: Would you give it a go yourself, and show us where you are getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query did the job for me. I had to remove AccID from Update since that is the PK and should not be updating.

```
INSERT INTO S_account(
    Sub, AccName, AccTeam, Terr, AccOwner, Level1, GAccount, Customer,
    City, State, EndCusName, AccID
) VALUES (
    "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "No", "Yes",
    "test", "test", "test", "asdasdas"
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Sub = VALUES(Sub), AccName = VALUES(AccName), AccTeam = VALUES(AccTeam),
    Terr = VALUES(Terr), AccOwner = VALUES(AccOwner),
    Level1 = VALUES(Level1), GAccount = VALUES(GAccount),
    Customer = VALUES(Customer), City = VALUES(City),
    State = VALUES(State), EndCusName = VALUES(EndCusName)
```